# SHCreateStreamOnFileEx on files larger than 2**32 bytes

Tags: c++, winapi, com

I'm getting an `IStream` for a file using [`SHCreateStreamOnFileEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759866(v=vs.85).aspx), but its `Read()` method appears to misbehave on extremely large files when the new position of the seek pointer is 2 ** 32 bytes or further into the file.

[`ISequentialStream::Read`'s documentation says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380011(v=vs.85).aspx):

> This method adjusts the seek pointer by the actual number of bytes read.

This is the same behaviour as `read(2)` and `fread(3)` on all platforms I'm aware of.

But with these streams, this isn't the actual behaviour I see in some cases:

- `Seek(2 ** 32 - 2, SEEK_SET, &pos)`, `Read(buf, 1, &bytesRead)`, `Seek(0, MOVE_CUR, &pos)` → `bytesRead == 1` and `pos == 2 ** 32 - 1`, as expected.
- `Seek(2 ** 32 - 1, SEEK_SET, &pos)`, `Read(buf, 1, &bytesRead)`, `Seek(0, MOVE_CUR, &pos)` → `bytesRead == 1`, but `pos == (2 ** 32 - 1) + 4096`, which is incorrect. This means that any subsequent reads (without another `Seek` to fix the cursor position) read the wrong data, and my application doesn't work!

Am I “holding it wrong”? Is there some flag I need to set to make this class behave properly? Or is this a bug in `Shlwapi.dll`?

The code below reproduces this problem for me. (Set `OFFSET = WORKS` to see the successful case.)

```
#include "stdafx.h"

static const int64_t TWO_THIRTY_TWO = 4294967296LL;
static const int64_t WORKS = TWO_THIRTY_TWO - 2LL;
static const int64_t FAILS = TWO_THIRTY_TWO - 1LL;
static const int64_t OFFSET = FAILS;

static void checkPosition(CComPtr< IStream > fileStream, ULONGLONG expectedPosition)
{
    LARGE_INTEGER move;
    ULARGE_INTEGER newPosition;

    move.QuadPart = 0;
    HRESULT hr = fileStream->Seek(move, SEEK_CUR, &newPosition);
    ASSERT(SUCCEEDED(hr));
    ULONGLONG error = newPosition.QuadPart - expectedPosition;
    ASSERT(error == 0);
}

int main()
{
    const wchar_t *path = /* path to a file larger than 2**32 bytes */ L"C:\\users\\wjt\\Desktop\\eos-eos3.1-amd64-amd64.170216-122002.base.img";
    CComPtr< IStream > fileStream;

    HRESULT hr;
    hr = SHCreateStreamOnFileEx(path, STGM_READ, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, FALSE, NULL, &fileStream);
    ASSERT(SUCCEEDED(hr));

    LARGE_INTEGER move;
    ULARGE_INTEGER newPosition;

    // Advance
    move.QuadPart = OFFSET;
    hr = fileStream->Seek(move, SEEK_SET, &newPosition);
    ASSERT(SUCCEEDED(hr));
    ASSERT(newPosition.QuadPart == OFFSET);

    // Check position
    checkPosition(fileStream, OFFSET);

    // Read
    char buf[1];
    ULONG bytesRead = 0;
    hr = fileStream->Read(buf, 1, &bytesRead);
    ASSERT(SUCCEEDED(hr));
    ASSERT(bytesRead == 1);

    // Check position: this assertion fails if the Read() call moves the cursor
    // across the 2**32 byte boundary
    checkPosition(fileStream, OFFSET + 1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: yes, can confirm. this is really windows bug

Comment: this is bug of `Shlwapi.dll` - current implementation not design for work with files more than `0xffffffff` size. all what you can do, if need IStream on large files - implement it yourself

Comment: @RbMm is this documented anywhere? Or is it just knowledge you accumulate? ☺

Comment: I simply test what you wrote - set offset to `0xffffffff` read 1 byte and check stream offset again. - `0x100000fff`. trace function call under debugger and view that this is `shlwapi` bug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is really windows bug. tested on several windows version including latest `SHCore.DLL` version `10.0.14393.0` x64. simple way for reproduce:

```
void BugDemo(PCWSTR path)
{
    // FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE !
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(path, FILE_GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_DELETE, 0, 
        CREATE_NEW, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY|FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE, 0);

    if (hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        ULONG dwBytesRet;
        // i not want really take disk space
        if (DeviceIoControl(hFile, FSCTL_SET_SPARSE, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, &dwBytesRet, NULL))
        {
            static FILE_END_OF_FILE_INFO eof = { 0, 2 };// 8GB
            if (SetFileInformationByHandle(hFile, FileEndOfFileInfo, &eof, sizeof(eof)))
            {
                IStream* pstm;
                if (!SHCreateStreamOnFileEx(path, STGM_READ|STGM_SHARE_DENY_NONE, 0,FALSE, NULL, &pstm))
                {
                    LARGE_INTEGER pos = { 0xffffffff };
                    ULARGE_INTEGER newpos;
                    if (!pstm->Seek(pos, STREAM_SEEK_SET, &newpos) && !pstm->Read(&newpos, 1, &dwBytesRet))
                    {
                        pos.QuadPart = 0;
                        if (!pstm->Seek(pos, STREAM_SEEK_CUR, &newpos))
                        {
                            DbgPrint("newpos={%I64x}\n", newpos.QuadPart);//newpos={100000fff}
                        }
                    }
                    pstm->Release();
                }
            }
        }

        // close and delete
        CloseHandle(hFile);
    }
}

void BugDemo()
{
    WCHAR path[MAX_PATH];
    if (ULONG len = GetTempPath(RTL_NUMBER_OF(path), path))
    {
        if (len + 16 < MAX_PATH)
        {
            FILETIME ft;
            GetSystemTimeAsFileTime(&ft);
            swprintf(path + len, L"%08x%08x", ~ft.dwLowDateTime, ft.dwHighDateTime);
            BugDemo(path);
        }
    }
}
```

I trace `virtual long CFileStream::Seek(LARGE_INTEGER, ULONG, ULARGE_INTEGER* );` under debugger and can confirm that this function not design to work with files more than 4GB size

---

if be more exactly, why is `100000FFF` offset - `CFileStream` use internal buffer for read `1000` byte size. when you ask read 1 byte from `FFFFFFFF` offset - it actually read `1000` bytes to the buffer and file offset become `100000FFF`. when you then call `Seek(0, STREAM_SEEK_CUR, &newpos)` - `CFileStream` call `SetFilePointer(hFile, 1-1000, 0/*lpDistanceToMoveHigh*/, FILE_CURRENT)`

(1 this is internal position in buffer, because we read 1 byte minus buffer size 1000) . if not take to account overflow can be `(100000FFF + (1 - 1000)) == 100000000` but

read about [`SetFilePointer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365541(v=vs.85).aspx)

> If *lpDistanceToMoveHigh* is **NULL** and the new file position does not fit
>   in a 32-bit value, the function fails and returns
>   **INVALID_SET_FILE_POINTER**.

as result `SetFilePointer` fail (return `INVALID_SET_FILE_POINTER`) but `CFileStream` even not check for this. and then it call `SetFilePointerEx(hFile, 0, &newpos, FILE_CURRENT)` and return to you newpos which still `100000FFF`

Comment: Thanks for going to the effort of stepping through in the debugger!

Comment: @wjt - i add explanation why this happens, why exactly  `100000FFF` offset. really stepping under debugger is very easy )